# How to retain the original value when a referenced cell changes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having a problem in MS-Excel. If I entered a value in sheet1 cell A1, that value appears everywhere that cell is referenced.  Is it possible to retain that value in the referencing cells if I erase the value in sheet1!A1?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to KEEP the text/value that is shown in a cell for "all future":

1. Select the cell
2. Select COPY from the menus/ribbon or hold CTRL and hit C
3. Immediately select "Paste special" from the menus/ribbon,
4. select "[v] Values" in the dialog that opened, then click OK

By this 'what was displayed' gets converted into the same TEXT, any formulas will vanish, and the text will stay until you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a formula that refers to `=Sheet1!A1`, it will show the value of cell A1 in Sheet1. If that cell value is deleted, the formula will return a 0.

That is how Excel works. A formula is re-calculated when the cells that contribute to the formula are changed. There is no way that a formula can show a value that no longer exists in a cell.

If you want to retain a value in a cell even after its original source (in another cell) is deleted, you will need VBA instead of a formula.

You may need to explain the bigger picture and detail the business logic that you want to apply before a perfect solution can be attempted.